# Definition of singular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have that $A$ and $B$ are non-singular $n \times n$ matrices. Then, how can we show that $AB$ is similar to $BA$?

To be similar, there exists an $S$ s.t. $S^{-1}AS = B$.

So I exploited definition, but it might mess up in terms of associativity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $A,B$ are non-singular $\implies A^{-1},B^{-1}$ exists. So,

$AB=(BAB)^{-1}(BA)(BAB)$

Comment: Just want to point out, more easily, $A^{-1}(AB)A=BA$.

Comment: lol.., Yes, that's a simple one.:) When i saw the question, first matrix came to my mind was $BAB$ and i checked if it satisfies. It did. Thanks anyways :)